# How to connect to multiple VPNs in Android

Tags: vpn

My university has a VPN and we need to connect to the VPN in order to get access to the internet. But, I want to contact to a workplace using internet.

Is there any way to have multiple book in Android. I mean like a VPN through another VPN?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [Android Developers - VpnService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html),

> There can be only one VPN connection running at the same time. The existing interface is deactivated when a new one is created.

So, no, you can only have one VPN at a time on Android. You can switch between the two, though, when you need to use the other.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two VPNs at the same time by using the [Android Work Profile](https://developer.android.com/work/managed-profiles). The Work Profile has it's own "VPN slot"; this allows you to be connected to two VPNs at the same time. You can set up the work profile using either [Island](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.island) or [Shelter](https://f-droid.org/packages/net.typeblog.shelter/) (FOSS)

Do note though that the work profile does not work well in some specific devices. I've confirmed it does work in a Moto e6+ with stock Android 9

Answer (score 0):

Depending on if your router has the feature, you could potentially connect your router to a VPN while connecting your phone to another, resulting at your phone connecting to two VPNs at the same time. BUT, this does not mean you can access two VPNs because VPN is an end to end encryption technology. You could however, effectively hide your packet from both router level VPN and your ISP (and therefore the NSA). It is a common technique for the cyber attackers.

Comment: using a VPN does not necessarily hide your traffic from the NSA. a VPN changes who you have to trust, not how much you have to trust them: instead of trusting your ISP, now you have to trust your VPN provider.