# Can you connect to multiple vpns at the same time on android 11?

Tags: settings, vpn

I have an always on VPN connection for security and privacy. I would like to connect to my home vpn for Music Player Deamon access. I would not like to announce my home IP to every WiFi I use. Can I and how to multi hop VPN on android 11, also second hop is conditional as I only want traffic for my system. I do not have root.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect to multiple VPN in android](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/87306/how-to-connect-to-multiple-vpn-in-android)

Comment: Not possible without root. With root you need to do manual configuration which requires at least basic familiarity with CLI.